# javassist.NotFoundException: com.baeldung.javasisst.Point

Tags: java, javassist

I am following this tutorial to learn javassist.
https://www.baeldung.com/javassist

I was trying to compile the libraries code from the tutorial below
https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/libraries
NOTE the some tutorial folders name javasisst

I was able to compile the project and generated

```
./target/classes/com/baeldung/javasisst/Point.class
```

But when I ran the unitest in test/java/javassist/JavasisstUnitTest folder

```java
public void givenJavaClass_whenLoadAtByJavassist_thenTraversWholeClass() throws NotFoundException, CannotCompileException, BadBytecode {
```

I got this error

```
javassist.NotFoundException: com.baeldung.javasisst.Point

    at javassist.ClassPool.get(ClassPool.java:452)
    at com.baeldung.javassist.JavasisstUnitTest.givenJavaClass_whenLoadAtByJavassist_thenTraversWholeClass(JavasisstUnitTest.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

I am confused because the `com.baeldung.javasisst.Point` should be the `./target/classes/com/baeldung/javasisst/Point.class`.

Java newbie here. Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: For me the module compiles and all tests pass both in Maven and when running the test class or a single method from IntelliJ IDEA. Without further information, I cannot say what causes your problem. What did you change in the code?

Comment: I did not change anything. How did you run the maven test?

Comment: `mvn test`, of course.